# How do you cleanly exit interactive Lua?

Tags: lua, scripting, exit, interactive

I've tried to the word "quit" on a single line but this seems to simply change the command line pointer from a ">" to a ">>". What's the best way to end a session in interactive Lua please?

Comment: The prompt changed to `>>`, because it expected an expression.

Comment: I like >> better for a prompt .. so maybe I'll type 'quit' to get that.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There is no `quit` keyword. Try control-D in Unix, control-Z in Windows or `os.exit()` if you must.

Comment: I've found one situation where only `os.exit()` works: the interactive lua shell  of the [lua.c32 syslinux module](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Lua.c32).

Answer (score 0):

Typing a full-stop/dot in the lua prompt works in my system -

```
Console# lua
lua>.
Console# lua
lua>hello
lua>>.
Console#
```